# When performing a POST to REST WCF Service get a Unrecognized exception

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I have a REST POST method as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
string GetFromXml(XElement xmlString);
```

I am trying to do a post operation from my client using the following code:

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "http://localhost/XMLRestService/XmlService.svc";
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Resource = "GetFromXml";
client.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");            
request.AddBody(obj, "XMLRestService");            
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

When i do the above i get a 400 Bad request. I then enabled tracing on the WCF Service. And the stack trace gave me a Unrecognized Message version excpetion that is thrown my the `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException` class.

I am unable to post the request successfully. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root cause to the exception. The below code works perfect:

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = serviceBaseUrl;
var request = new RestRequest(method){RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml};
request.Resource = resourceUrl;
request.AddParameter("text/xml",requestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

The requestBody being sent as parameter should be a serialized xmlString.

**NOTE**: If the composite type exposed on the REST Service is using DataContractSerializer then make sure to generate the requestBody using DataContractSerializer and if uses XmlSerializer then generate the requestBody using XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is using application/xml instead of text/xml

Answer (score 0):

enclose your request in a soap envelope.  I DIY my requests and I got this error when I forgot to do the needful.

contract-first, javascript, ajax, jquery, all require you handle the details.  Such a no brainer on my part, but I struggled for hours w/o seeing the obvious.